# How to debug my android application in device

Tags: android

How can I debug my android application in a device, not in the emulator. because I get a problem in application testing on the device but at the same time in the emulator I can't find any problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Eclipse, you can use the build in Debugger.
Just remember to set your phone to Debuggable and put this in your Manifest:

```
<application 
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to turn the USB debugging setting on your phone ON.  Do it here:

```
Settings->Applications->Development->USB degugging
```

Make sure that's on.

Answer (score 2):

***Method-1***
If you are developing the app in eclipse then follow these steps:-
1. Go to AndroidManifest.xml -> Application tab -> Debugabble (dropdown) true.
 Description - This will enable the debug mode for your application
2. Now identify the code area where you have doubt of an error.
3. Open the activity code window
4. Double click on the leftmost part(left of line number on the code window) of the identified error line of the code area. 
5. Now Click on Run option(upper side of the window) -> Debug
Now you have the full description of the above part before the selected line.

**Note**:- Attach the device with your system before the 5th step
You can also select the first line after the onCreate() and with F6 you can enter into next line.

You can follow - http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

***Method-2***
You can write Toast to print the varible's values on the device screen.